# Objective-C Program Received Signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" push notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, exc-bad-access, apple-push-notifications

I've been coding Objective-C for a whole 2 days.
I have this problem:

```
//Notification methods
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken started with %@", deviceToken);   
    const void *devTokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
    self->registered = YES;
    //NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken ended with %@", devTokenBytes);  
    [self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes];
}

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError started with %@", error);  
}

- (BOOL)sendProviderDeviceToken:(void *)deviceToken
{

    //NSLog(@"sendProviderDeviceToken started with %@", deviceToken);   
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some_url//pushRegistration"]];
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:deviceToken, @"registrationId", @"06d746d0-e67e-11e0-911d-c42c0322474a", @"authenticationToken", @"apns", @"type", nil];

    NSError *theError = NULL;
    NSData *theData = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeObject:dict error:&theError];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[theData bytes] length:[theData length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"returnData: %@", returnString);   

    return YES;
}
```

You probably recognize this example from Apple Dev Center.
The problem is I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal when trying to reference deviceToken in sendProviderDeviceToken method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If my answer helped as per your comment, please mark that as accepted so that other users found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Device token can be used as string too (Below snippet is from one of my live project),

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

    NSString *strDeviceToken = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[[[deviceToken description]
                                                          stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] 
                                                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                                         withString:@""]];
    NSLog(@"%@",strDeviceToken);

    [self sendProviderDeviceToken:strDeviceToken];

}
```

Change signature of method from this

```
- (BOOL)sendProviderDeviceToken:(void *)deviceToken
```

to

```
- (BOOL)sendProviderDeviceToken:(NSString *)deviceToken
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try using a NSString instead?

```
NSString *tokenString = [[[[[deviceToken description] 
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""] 
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] 
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""] uppercaseString];
```

Comment: Problem is solved thanks to @Jennis answer. and she did used a NSString.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set deviceToken  in dictionary so it should be an object type of string .

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{

      const unsigned *tokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
            NSString *deviceUDID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                          ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];

     [self sendProviderDeviceToken:devTokenBytes];

}
```

AND Method should be in string type:

```
- (BOOL)sendProviderDeviceToken:(NSString *)deviceToken
```

This will work for you!

Thanks